# How to send a string through a socket in python to a java server?

Tags: python, string, sockets

I have the following problem:
I made a simple java server and a python client, but, since I am new to python I don't know how to send a string over the socket, so that the java server can read it the right way. This is some of the code of the client (written in Python 3.5).
The part with sock.send(b"1-4\n") successfully did the job and I got from the server the expected message.

```
...................
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.send(b"1-4\n")
data = sock.recv(102451223).decode()  
print(data) 
....................
```

But let's say that I want to get the input from the user and they only write "1-4". How to send the string input (I have input=("enter range:")) ?
I tried with

```
sock.send(b""+input+"\n")
```

and it didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give us the stack? Does it even throw an Exception?

Comment: Read up on [how to use sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) (see the implementation of `mysocket.mysend()`). Just calling sock.send(mystuff) is unhygienic. It'll almost always work, but every once in a while it won't, and you'll spend weeks tearing your hair out over it. In practice, the first few bytes you send over a socket are pretty much guaranteed to be accepted in full on the first call to `send()`, but making such assumptions is bad karma.

Comment: range_input = input(" Enter the ID")
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.send((str(input) + "\n").encode())
data = sock.recv(102451223).decode()

does not work :(
print(data)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you encode your string:

```
socket.send(("string1" + "string2").encode())
```

This should do the thing.

**Explanation**:

Your code only encodes the first part of the string, but you have to encode the complete text that should be sent to the server.

Comment: I tried range_input = input(" Enter the ID-range ")
sock.send((str(input)).encode()) ,but it doesn't work...

Comment: You have to use `sock.send((str(range_input).encode())`

Answer (score 1):

So guys, after some struggling for some time, I found a solution:

```
 range_input =input(" Enter the ID-range")
 stringTosend = (str(range_input)+"\n")
 sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
 sock.send(stringTosend.encode())
```

I got the right information from the java server

Answer (score 0):

```
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
z = input('to Server: ')
s.sendall(bytes(z, encoding='utf8'))#(sz.encode())#
```

this worked for me

but in my case, my error is when typing `z = input('to Server: ')`, I must have a space at the end (before hitting the enter key), so string which I have just typed will show